# On the closed-form of $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dxdydz}{1-\frac{z}{3}(x+\sqrt{xy}+y)}$

Tags: integration

I would like to know if it is possible to calculate in closed-form, or well what work can be done about it, the definite integral $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{3dxdydz}{3-z(x+\sqrt{xy}+y)},\tag{1}$$
where I was inspired in a well-known integral representation for the Apéry constant involving the volume $x\cdot y\cdot z$ in the denominator, and in the formula for the volume of a square frustum of basis $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$ and height $z$, as reference for all I add the Wikipedia [*Heronian mean.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_mean)

It is easy to check the integration of the logartihm $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{3-z(x+\sqrt{xy}+y)}dz=\frac{\log 3-\log(3-x-\sqrt{xy}-y)}{x+\sqrt{xy}+y}$$
but the computations using a CAS (and standard time of computation with my computer), that I tried after this step, seems to me very tedious to evaluate. I suspect that now an important key to evaluate it should be to exploit symmetry or a suitable change of variable.

> **Question.** I would like to know if it is possible to evaluate in closed-form (in terms of well-known constants and/or particular values of special functions) previous definite integral $(1)$. If isn't feasible to get the closed-form that I evoke explain why or add what work can be done. **Many thanks.**

If this integral is in the literature feel free to refer the literature in your answer or comment and I can to read the result from the literature.

**Edit: (see comments, please).** I don't know if from this step one can to get the integral in closed-form. Feel free to do more feedback, many thanks.

Using previous hints in comments I can to write that it is possible to reduce the integral over $xy$ to one-dimensional integral by using polar coordinates in $xy$-plane

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dxdy}{1-\frac{z}{3}(x+\sqrt{xy}+y)}=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\sec \theta}\frac{drd\theta}{\frac{3}{r}-z(\cos\theta+\sqrt{\cos\theta\sin\theta}+\sin\theta)},$$ 
where the inner integral is equals to $$\int_0^{\sec\theta}\frac{dr}{\frac{3}{r}-z(\cos\theta+\sqrt{\cos\theta\sin\theta}+\sin\theta)}=\frac{-A\sec\theta-3\log(3-A\sec\theta)+3\log 3}{A^2},$$
being $A=z(\cos\theta+\sqrt{\cos\theta\sin\theta}+\sin\theta)$.

---

Since the integral seems very difficult I am going to accept an answer showing what work can be done (see the **Question**) as soon as expires the bounty.

Comment: MSE is a right forum for such questions.

Comment: Good afternoon, I must assume that you already know the closed formula for the integral @user64494 ?

Comment: Note that for the credibility of your comment, (I can be wrong, and acknowledge it to you) you could add that you know the answer. I don't see what is the problem, if you are right, I can say *I'm sorry* and delete my post. Isn't? Do you know the answer @user64494 ?

Comment: It is possible to reduce the integral over xy to one-dimensional integral by using polar coordinates in xy plane. After integrating over r there will remain a trigonometric integral.

Comment: I don't want to disturb, if there are more feedback I should delete my post in the next few hours. Many thanks @user64494 but I think that the right way to evidence that some post is wrong for this site is provide more feedback. My question is a non-orthodox version of the aforementioned integral representation for the Apèry constant. I don't know if using the previous comment the trigonometric integral is easy to get.

Comment: How does the integral over the unit square become an integral over the unit disk? Isn't there an issue with bounds here?

Comment: Yes, I delete it @MichaelRenardy

Comment: All, after I've undeleted the question and follow the hints of previous users, feel free to do feedback about the post. My belief is that the integral is difficult, but if I'm wrong or if isn't possible to get in closed-form (in closed-form as was posed in the **Question**) the integral maybe the post 
it's not as useful as I think. Many thanks all users.

Comment: If there isn't typo this is the code that I known before asking my question in MathOverflow, from Wolfram Alpha online calculator `int (log 3 -log(3 + (-x - y - sqrt(x y))))/(x + y + sqrt(x y))dx`  Do you think that the integral $(1)$ is easy to get @user64494 ?

Comment: There is a lot of integrals which are not expressed in closed form. Such questions are for MSE, not for MO.

Comment: I disagree, as I often do, with @user64494 who has rather idiosyncratic views about what counts as mathematical research. There is no apriori reason why this question should be on MSE rather than MO

Comment: You didn't understand my comment correctly. I meant use polar coordinates in xy plane after integrating over z variable.

Comment: Many thanks @YemonChoi I am here to learn from all users and of course from the mentioned user, and to me don't like myself comments. I would like it to be clarified in the next few hours/days if it is possible to make a nice post question/answer and delete myself comments, because I like 
harmony and peace-

Comment: Then I'm sorry @Nemo

Comment: Any specific reason why you chose to use $x, y$ as integration variables, rather than substituting $u = \sqrt{x}, v = \sqrt{y}$? That would leave a rational function with no square roots, which I usually think is nicer.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @user44191 , this was the integral that I've considered, but of course you can to study a different integral in your home (feel free to comment here if you're able to get the integral that you are evoking)

Comment: @user142929 I think I may have been unclear; I was suggesting a possible start of a method: let $u = \sqrt{x}, dx = 2u du, v = \sqrt{y}, dy = 2vdv$, rendering your integral equal to $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{12 uv du dv dz}{3 - z(u^2 + uv + v^2)}$. However, as it is your integral, it is entirely possible that you have a reason for preferring the square root version. (Corrected mistake)

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution, feel free to add your approach in an answer. What I understand is what perhaps there were other more beautiful variants of my integral; I sometimes understand my posts as an invitation to others to do their own research. Thank you very much again @user44191

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me expand the integrand in powers of $z$ and integrate over $z$,
$$I=\int_0^1 dx\int_0^1 dy\int_0^1 dz\;\frac{3}{3-z(x+\sqrt{xy}+y)}$$
$$\qquad\qquad=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\frac{3^{-n}}{n+1} \int_0^1 dx\int_0^1 dy\;(x+\sqrt{xy}+y)^n.$$
The integral over $x$ and $y$ is an element $c_{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$,
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\frac{3^{-n}}{n+1}c_n,\;\;c_n=\int_0^1 dx\int_0^1 dy\;(x+\sqrt{xy}+y)^n,$$
$$\{c_0,c_1,c_2,\ldots\}=\{1,\tfrac{13}{9},\tfrac{149}{60},\tfrac{1667}{350},\tfrac{18623}{1890},\tfrac{69667}{3234},\ldots\}.$$
I have not yet succeeded in finding a closed-form expression for $c_n$ valid for all integer $n$, but that seems doable. At least we would then have the desired integral as a sum over rational coefficients.

---

<sub>With FusRoDah's input for $c_n$, and carrying out the sum over $n$, I find
$$I=\sum_{a,b=0}^\infty\frac{12 \Gamma (a+b+1) \left(3^{-a-\frac{b}{2}} B_{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\frac{b}{2}+1,-a-b\right)-B_{\frac{1}{3}}(a+b+1,-a-b)\right)}{(2 a+b) (2 a+b+2) \Gamma (a+1) \Gamma (b+1)},$$
(with $B$ the incomplete beta function).</sub>

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, your answers are always very good.

Comment: Set $x^2=u$, $y^2=v$ and expand with the multinimial theorem. I got something like $c_n=4n! \sum_{a+b+c=n} \frac 1 {a!b!c! (2a+b+2)(2c+b+2)}$

Comment: @FusRoDah --- wonderful!

Comment: This converges rather slowly.  Experimentally, the ratios $c_{n+1}/c_n$ converge to $3$, so if we put $d_n=c_n 3^{-n}/(n+1)$ then $d_{n+1}/d_n$ converges to $1$.  Initially the $d$'s drop quite quickly with $d_{100}\approx 4\times 10^{-6}$, but the decrease seems much slower after that, with $d_{200}\approx 5\times 10^{-7}$ and $d_{1000}\approx 4\times 10^{-9}$.